# Why Nagios doesn't accept external commands on my system?

Tags: nagios

I have enabled external commands, and they do work from the web interface.

I have enabled external command logging.

I write to the socket with this script:

```
$ echo "[`date +%s`] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;carroll;0;icingaadmin;comment" | sudo -u nagios tee -a /var/lib/icinga/rw/icinga.cmd
[1314390099] ADD_HOST_COMMENT;carroll;0;icingaadmin;comment
$ grep EXTERNAL /var/log/icinga/icinga.log | tail -n 1
[1314390100] EXTERNAL COMMAND: ADD_HOST_COMMENT;carroll;0;icingaadmin;comment
```

And I don't see new comment in the webinterface!

What's wrong?

Comment: restarted the whole server and now external commands work.... mystery.

Answer (score 0):

If there was no restart (your comment isn't persistent) then I'm guessing you have the wrong `host_name` or have used the host's `alias` or are not authorized to see extended host information in the web interface.

Comment: tried both persistent and non-persistent comments. host name is correct (double checked), i can add comments through web interface and see them.

Answer (score 0):

No need to restart. Did you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> several times to refresh the web interface?

Comment: yes, i have done that.

Comment: What is permission of `cmd.cgi`? And which group did you use when configuring icinga `--with-command-group`? Did you add nagios/icinga to this group?

Comment: installed from debian packages. restarted server and now it works. Strange.